# How to download files from a database, and get them as image in Asp.net core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have been reading and working around downloading and uploading files to database! I just made upload work, so now i save my files in Binary in the database! Also i display the name in the View :

```
@model IEnumerable<RH_Files>

<div class="tableContainer">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(p => p.Name)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
              <tr>
                  <td>
                      @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)
                  </td>
              </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

as you can see :
[image]

my model:

```
 public class RH_Files
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public Byte[] Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Now what i need, is to have a download button for each item, that will trigger a c# action that downloads the file selected...

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: in your controller create an action that returns File(...)

Comment: Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52048287/how-to-retrieve-file-from-database) about retrieve file from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your controller:

```
public FileResult Download(int id)
{
      var fileToRetrieve = db.GetFile(id);
      return File(fileToRetrieve.Data, fileToRetrieve.ContentType);
}
```

Comment: Do i change that db. for  _context.RH_Files ? if so its giving me an error, it says it does not contain definition for GetFile.

Comment: That was just an example. there you need to get the file from the database

Comment: and if you want to view a file create another method but return Content instead of File